# Knockout trigger function on Audio end

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a Knockout audio app and I've got a function set up that's bound to a KO click event and the purpose of the function is to load and play the next track in the playlist / array when 'Next' is selected.

I want to be able to trigger this 'next track' function when the current track has finished playing. I've tried doing `$('audio').addEventListener('ended', setNextTrack);` inside and outside of my viewModel but it just doesn't work.

Anybody any ideas how I can trigger my KO setNextTrack function when the current audio has completed?

Comment: Have you tried to use the event binding? `<audio controls="controls"  data-bind="attr: { src: Url }, event: { ended: setNextTrack }" type="audio/mp3"></audio>`

Comment: I hadn't no and this worked perfectly; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) to subscribe on any event like the `ended` event on  audio element.

And with the `event` binding you can trigger your `setNextTrack` function:

```
<audio controls="controls"  
    data-bind="attr: { src: Url }, event: { ended: setNextTrack }" 
    type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```